# How to return a boolean value for multiple ranges of numbers?

Tags: sql, ms-access, categorical-data, iif

I am trying to use an IIF function to create a dummy variable in a make table query in Access '13 and I  am running into some problems on how to construct the ranges.

Essentially, I have three columns of categorical data in a table with numbers ranging 1 through 9 that correspond to my data. I want to return a boolean if the values of all three columns are between 4 and 9.

This is what I have tried and it returns a column of all true values, which I know not to be the case.
nonmetro:

```
IIf((4>=[Beale All Versions Together]![1983 Rural-urban Continuum Code]<=9) 
And (4>=[Beale All Versions Together]![1993 Rural-urban Continuum Code]<=9)
And (4>=[Beale All Versions Together]![2003 Rural-urban Continuum Code]<=9),1,0)
```

Comment: I deleted a lot of content from this post, verify that I understood correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use logic for your expression:

```
CodesAre4To9:
[Beale All Versions Together]![1983 Rural-urban Continuum Code] Between 4 And 9 
And 
[Beale All Versions Together]![1993 Rural-urban Continuum Code] Between 4 And 9 
And 
[Beale All Versions Together]![2003 Rural-urban Continuum Code] Between 4 And 9
```